# How can I sleep for the difference between 5 minutes and the start time in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time, timestamp

I'm trying to figure out why this won't work:

```
loop do

  started = Time.now

  # do stuff

  ended = Time.now - started

  if 5.minutes > ended
    sleep ended
  end

end
```

Comment: how exactly doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code sleeps for the length of time that the original process took (the value of `ended`). Which makes the whole loop time half "doing stuff", half sleep. You should probably just change the sleep line to

```
sleep 5.minutes - ended
```

instead, if I understand the question correctly, and that you wish to run the process once every 5 minutes, taking account of how long it takes to complete.

You might want to consider using `cron` instead, if setup time to get to the loop is not too high.

Comment: That was a "what was I thinking" moment. So sleep will not crash on a negative number?

Comment: `sleep` *will* fail for a negative number, so you still need the `if`